# Firebase download error Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to download an data from Firebase, I get fail only on iOS 8 devices, other devices run good, I'm getting this error:

> Firebase download error Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." UserInfo=0x1471bf10 {ResponseErrorDomain=NSURLErrorDomain, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/api-project-xxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/o/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%2Fdata.xx?alt=media, object=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/data.xx, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/api-project-xxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/o/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%2Fdata.xx?alt=media, ResponseErrorCode=-1100, bucket=api-project-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.}

Here is my code:

```
    FIRStorageReference *islandRef = [[self class] firebaseStorageReference];
    NSURL *localURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:DocumentPath(kFIREBASE_STORAGE_NAME)];
    __weak typeof(PCMergeHandler*) weakSelf = self;
    self.storageTask = [islandRef writeToFile:localURL completion:^(NSURL *URL, NSError *error){

    }];
```

Any help provided would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1888#issuecomment-431544373

Comment: Thanks, I was calling the api on main thread, but the error still happen and only bellow iOS 9 devices, other devices is good. @PaulBeusterien

Comment: I replace dataWithMaxSize:completion: to writeToFile:completion:, this problem is solved.